# Celery tasks return typeError, but no error on worker log

Tags: python, celery

I have a program with structure like this:

```
program/worker.py
       /package/sub-package/file.py
                            usecase.py
```

I declare the app of celery on worker.py:

```
from celery import Celery
app = Celery('program.worker',
             broker=redis_broker,
             include=['program.package.sub-package.file'])
```

And the tasks is written like this on file.py:

```
from program.worker import app

class File():
    @propery
    somefunction():

    @app.task
    celeryFunction(param1):
    print(param1)
```

When I call the tasks from a function inside usecase.py:

```
from program.package.sub-package.file import celeryFunction

def run(param):
    celeryFunction.delay(param)
```

I got error, but the celery worker log didnot print anything about error, Is there something I miss?

Thank you

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: typeError exception @Lomtrur

Comment: Post the full error please and how you call your `run`.

Answer (score 0):

It turn's out I need to put:

```
@app.task(bind=True)
```

after i put it on the task function, i can call it without error.

Thank you everyone!